# Convert Excel spreadsheet to HTML by XSLT transformation of XML

Tags: excel, xml, asp.net-core, xslt

I have a requirement to preview excel files in browser. I could generate an XML for the worksheet. I am trying to convert the XML to HTML by XSLT transformation. I am able to get the data in table format. I could not get the style part in xsl. Below is the XML for a sample spreadsheet.I am new to XSLT transformations, how can I extract the styles in dataprops and cellprops nodes and add it to table, tr and td styles.

```
<Data>
  <DataProps>
    <sheetFormatPr defaultColWidth="9.25" defaultRowHeight="15" dyDescent="0.25" />
  </DataProps>
  <Row RowNumber="1">
    <Cell Ref="A1" ColumnId="A" ColumnNumber="0" Type="s">
      <CellProps />
      <Value>Make </Value>
      <DisplayValue>Make </DisplayValue>
    </Cell>
    <Cell Ref="B1" ColumnId="B" ColumnNumber="1" Type="s">
      <CellProps />
      <Value>Miles </Value>
      <DisplayValue>Miles </DisplayValue>
    </Cell>
    <Cell Ref="C1" ColumnId="C" ColumnNumber="2" Type="s">
      <CellProps />
      <Value>Cost</Value>
      <DisplayValue>Cost</DisplayValue>
    </Cell>
  </Row>
  <Row RowNumber="2">
    <Cell Ref="A2" ColumnId="A" ColumnNumber="0" Type="s">
      <CellProps />
      <Value>Ford</Value>
      <DisplayValue>Ford</DisplayValue>
    </Cell>
    <Cell Ref="B2" ColumnId="B" ColumnNumber="1">
      <CellProps />
      <Value>40000</Value>
      <DisplayValue>40000</DisplayValue>
    </Cell>
    <Cell Ref="C2" ColumnId="C" ColumnNumber="2" Style="1">
      <CellProps numFmtId="6" formatCode="&quot;$&quot;#,##0_);[Red]\(&quot;$&quot;#,##0\)" applyNumberFormat="1">
        <font>
          <sz val="11" />
          <color theme="1" />
          <name val="Calibri" />
          <family val="Swiss" />
          <scheme val="minor" />
        </font>
      </CellProps>
      <Value>3500</Value>
      <DisplayValue>$3,500</DisplayValue>
    </Cell>
  </Row>
  <Row RowNumber="3">
    <Cell Ref="A3" ColumnId="A" ColumnNumber="0" Type="s">
      <CellProps />
      <Value>Chevi</Value>
      <DisplayValue>Chevi</DisplayValue>
    </Cell>
    <Cell Ref="B3" ColumnId="B" ColumnNumber="1">
      <CellProps />
      <Value>55000</Value>
      <DisplayValue>55000</DisplayValue>
    </Cell>
    <Cell Ref="C3" ColumnId="C" ColumnNumber="2" Style="1">
      <CellProps numFmtId="6" formatCode="&quot;$&quot;#,##0_);[Red]\(&quot;$&quot;#,##0\)" applyNumberFormat="1">
        <font>
          <sz val="11" />
          <color theme="1" />
          <name val="Calibri" />
          <family val="Swiss" />
          <scheme val="minor" />
        </font>
      </CellProps>
      <Value>4200</Value>
      <DisplayValue>$4,200</DisplayValue>
    </Cell>
  </Row>
  <Row RowNumber="4">
    <Cell Ref="A4" ColumnId="A" ColumnNumber="0" Type="s">
      <CellProps />
      <Value>Tata</Value>
      <DisplayValue>Tata</DisplayValue>
    </Cell>
    <Cell Ref="B4" ColumnId="B" ColumnNumber="1">
      <CellProps />
      <Value>51000</Value>
      <DisplayValue>51000</DisplayValue>
    </Cell>
    <Cell Ref="C4" ColumnId="C" ColumnNumber="2" Style="1">
      <CellProps numFmtId="6" formatCode="&quot;$&quot;#,##0_);[Red]\(&quot;$&quot;#,##0\)" applyNumberFormat="1">
        <font>
          <sz val="11" />
          <color theme="1" />
          <name val="Calibri" />
          <family val="Swiss" />
          <scheme val="minor" />
        </font>
      </CellProps>
      <Value>3800</Value>
      <DisplayValue>$3,800</DisplayValue>
    </Cell>
  </Row>
</Data>
```

Below is the xsl sheet generated.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <!-- This is the identity transformation, it is the default action -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- This transforms Data to  table-->
    <xsl:template match="Data">
        <table>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- This transforms Row to tr -->
    <xsl:template match="Row">
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- This transforms Cell to td -->
    <xsl:template match="Cell">
        <td>
<xsl:value-of select="DisplayValue"/>           
        </td>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Currently I am getting an output in the below format:

```
<table>
  
  <tbody><tr rownumber="1">
    <td>Make </td>
    <td>Miles </td>
    <td>Cost</td>
  </tr>
  <tr rownumber="2">
    <td>Ford</td>
    <td>40000</td>
    <td>$3,500</td>
  </tr>
  <tr rownumber="3">
    <td>Chevi</td>
    <td>55000</td>
    <td>$4,200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr rownumber="4">
    <td>Tata</td>
    <td>51000</td>
    <td>$3,800</td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

I would like to extract the styles from the xml ( which is present in dataprops, cell props etc) and add as style (inline style/css style sheet) to table, tr , td.

Comment: Please add the expected output to your question.

Comment: edited to add expected output.

Comment: No, you haven't.

Comment: Please check edited to add expected output